# Insert Byte string into MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have some bytestrings that I need to insert.

```
> db.test2.t.insert({'e': '\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe'})
> db.test2.t.insert({'e': '\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe'})
> db.test2.t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5152e927d50568b4a9b56cdd"), "e" : " Çeê\u0014¾g·ßÊgFNø\u0013¾" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5152e9e9d50568b4a9b56cde"), "e" : " Çeê\u0014¾g·ßÊgFNø\u0013¾" }
```

I can't read that same byte string out in Python:

```
>>> e =  " Çeê\u0014¾g·ßÊgFNø\u0013¾"
>>> e
'\xc2\xa0\xc3\x87e\xc3\xaa\\u0014\xc2\xbeg\xc2\xb7\xc3\x9f\xc3\x8agFN\xc3\xb8\\u0013\xc2\xbe'
>>> g =  b'\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe'
>>> g
'\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe'
```

Thanks.

---

Encode as utf8

```
>>> u'\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe'.encode('utf8')
'\xc2\xa0\xc3\x87e\xc3\xaa\x14\xc2\xbeg\xc2\xb7\xc3\x9f\xc3\x8agFN\xc3\xb8\x13\xc2\xbe'
```

When I insert that, I am getting

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5152ee3ad50568b4a9b56ce0"), "e" : "Â ÃeÃª\u0014Â¾gÂ·ÃÃgFNÃ¸\u0013Â¾" }
```

But clearly when I decode that with `utf8`,

```
u'\xc2\xa0\xc3\x87e\xc3\xaa\\u0014\xc2\xbeg\xc2\xb7\xc3\x9f\xc3\x8agFN\xc3\xb8\\u0013\xc2\xbe'
```

This is what I put in. Great. But how do I decode back to the original one?

Comment: Could it be an encoding problem? Maybe MongoDB uses a different character encoding than Python.

Comment: MongoDB uses UTF-8 encoding to store byte arrays as Binary Data. Try encoding your string as UTF-8

Comment: Thanks both. @orid I don't think I could encode it as utf8 due to ``UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)``. by doing ``byte_string.encode('utf-8')``

Comment: Ny bad. See my edit. I got the unicode. I can see the unicode when I decode, but I still can't get back the original before encode was applied.

Comment: you need to know what encoding in which your original string was coded.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Binary` type:

```
> db.test.t.insert({'e': BinData(0, 'oMdl6hS+Z7ffymdGTvgTvg==')})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.t.insert({'e': BinData(0, 'oMdl6hS+Z7ffymdGTvgTvg==')})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.t.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e4a1d51b696fa210e6d074"), "e" :     BinData(0,"oMdl6hS+Z7ffymdGTvgTvg==") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e4a1d71b696fa210e6d075"), "e" :     BinData(0,"oMdl6hS+Z7ffymdGTvgTvg==") }
```

And from Python:

```
>>> cli.test.test.t.find()
[{u'_id': ObjectId('56e4a1d51b696fa210e6d074'), u'e': Binary('\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe', 0)}, 
 {u'_id': ObjectId('56e4a1d71b696fa210e6d075'), u'e': Binary('\xa0\xc7e\xea\x14\xbeg\xb7\xdf\xcagFN\xf8\x13\xbe', 0)}]
```